# How to use multiple sorting criteria across multiple content types?

Tags: views

I'd like to display a view of several content types on my frontpage (news, events, products, artists). That's easily done.

However I also need to sort the posts in a pretty specific way. It's a bit hard to explain but here we go:

News and artists should be sorted by publish date.
Events should be sorted by a date field (event date).
Products should be sorted by a date field (release date).

Here's an example of how the first 5 posts on my front page could look all together on a random day:

- Sep 15 (publish date) - News post 1
- Sep 14 (event date) - Event post 1 (could be published on a much earlier date)
- Sep 13 (publish date) - News post
- Sep 12 (release date) - Product post 1 (could be published
  on a much earlier date)
- Sep 11 (event date) - Event post 2 (could be
  published on a much earlier date) etc. etc.

I don't see any way to set sorting criteria per content type within the same view though? Any ideas? Or did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you are suggesting with Views as written.  The **Sort** criteria applies to everything being sorted by the view.

I would suggest adding a date field to all content types you want to sort called **Sort**, and then use hooks in a custom module to automatically set the value for the field when possible (for example, automatically set the date field's value to the publish date upon publishing for news posts).

Then you can easily sort by the single (newly created) date field in Views.

Comment: Great and simple idea, love it